# windows additional desktop-like container

Tags: windows-7

Is there a windows application which would allow to organize file and folder icons in containers which visually behave like desktop. By this, I mean: the desktop-like container should remember the screen coordinates where the icon is placed and allow to choose the icon for files and child containers. Nothing else special, just this.

Windows desktop is ideal for it.

The problem with Windows desktop is that it is only 1. I would need several ("Home", "Work", "Internet").

Furthermore, the original Windows desktop does not allow me to create a child container which is also a desktop-like container, the only container that can be created on a desktop is a regular folder. And folder does not allow to place icons inside of it in specific places (screen coordinates), it just displays them sorted.

I have read about "Virtual desktops" but this is probably not what I am looking for. Virtual desktops don't have common workspace (task bar), they are completely separated. I am looking only for a way to organize stuff visually, not to create separate environments like e.g. for separately logged-in users.

In other words, I am looking for special kind of folders: folders that allow to place children at specific coordinates and remember those, and allow to choose children icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Stardock Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/).

Comment: Thats what i'd suggest but you beat me to it. There's a very similar concept in plasma/kde by default as well

Comment: I just installed Fences but they are missing two features: the possibility to place icons in a specific place inside the fence (instead, icons are sorted automatically) and do not allow to create nested fences. I will try them for some time, maybe this will work without those features. But I have quite limited screen surface, so the lack of nested containers may be similar problem as with regular folders.

Comment: Actually, Fences is quite comfortable.